# Self-referential nodes in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm, graph-modelling-language

Is it ok if we create self-referential nodes in neo4j? I need to use it in a big data environment so the performance really matters.
I found an example [here](http://www.simosh.com/article/dfhfdhag-neo4j-parent-child-heirarchy-spring.html) but need to know more opinions about this. Generally which one is better ? to use self reference nodes or to break them down to separate nodes with different labels and relations?
My scenario is to create ecommerce tag groups and tags. A TAG_GROUP has TAGs ,  this is clear. However some Tags might have subtags. So there can be 2 solutions for this :

1) To use TAG-[has]-TAG self-referencial tag with some properties like {parentID,isSubTag,...}, the good thing about this is that I can go more than one sub-Tag level. However I am not sure how the performance will be.

2)To use TAH-[has]-SUB_TAG. Well maybe this one is simpler and easier to understand. But what if the SUB_TAG has a SUB_SUB tag itself?

Any help would be appreciated.

P.S.I am going to use neo4j 3.0.1 standalone server and Spring-Data-neo4j 4.1.1

Comment: I'm not sure this question is a good fit for the site since there is no one answer. I would recommend taking the approach that is cleanest and best fits your data model, only worrying about performance if you have problems in practice. I cannot discern why the two approaches you describe would perform differently; self-referencing or not should make no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Speaking outside of the use case of SDN, what you describe is a hierarchy, which can definitely be naturally modelled in Neo4J.

The notion of parent/child just have to be done with relationships, no need for properties.

```
(Tag)-[:CHILD]->(Tag)-[:CHILD]->(Tag)
```

I assume you would have products with associated tags, a Tag can then `tags` a product:

```
(Tag)-[:TAGS]->(Product)
```

Finding the associated tag for a product is as easy as :

```
MATCH (product:Product {id: 1})
OPTIONAL MATCH (product)<-[:TAGS]-(tag)
RETURN product, collect(tags) as tag
```

The OPTIONAL MATCH takes into account products not having tags without breaking the query

If you want the complete hierarchy of tags per tag tagging the product

```
MATCH (product:Product {id: 1})
OPTIONAL MATCH (product)<-[:TAGS]-()<-[:CHILD*0..]-(tag)
RETURN product, collect(tag) as tags
```

Here the 0 is taking into account the case where the tags doesn't have parents and will embed the `()` in the `tags` collection.

I suggest you the following reads for the modelling and Cypher parts, I'm sure someone can add an answer for the SDN side of this.

http://graphaware.com/neo4j/2013/10/11/neo4j-bidirectional-relationships.html

http://graphaware.com/graphaware/2015/05/19/neo4j-cypher-variable-length-relationships-by-example.html

Comment: Thanks Christopher. (Tag)-[:CHILD]->(Tag)-[:CHILD]->(Tag) is exactly the case that I needed to clarify.
BTW links were very very useful ! Thanks for that !